# how to create image slideshow from jquery arrays generated by php

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-slider

For starters I do not have any code written. My question is along the lines how to use Arrays with jQuery to scroll through their values.

I would like to iterate arrays with values of the arrays being URL's to the thumbnails provided by PHP.

So for example.

```
<?php

$folderThumbArray = array(
http://cdn.sitename.ltd/md3slk3.th.jpg,
http://cdn.sitename.ltd/n3oqPls.th.jpg,
http://cdn.sitename.ltd/l9nkAla.th.jpg,
http://cdn.sitename.ltd/P9jKLmn.th.jpg,
http://cdn.sitename.ltd/9nsJUol.th.jpg,
);

$objThumbArray = print_r($folderThumbArray);

?>
```

The following code would select and create arrays from a folder and then hand them over to jQuery.

What can I do with jQuery to allow it to scroll through this Arrays as if a miniature sideshow?

Comment: Please provide some code with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Youre going to want to do something like this..

```
<div id="slideShow">
<?php
foreach($folderThumbArray as $val){
    echo '<img src="'$val'" />';
}
?>
</div>
```